# Delete rows which codes are not present in other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables airports, location and location hint. After update of location table I need to remove airport names, which are no longer present in location's n_airports column, where n_airpots column is a collection of airports codes devided by coma. I tried to delete one by one selecting by Lik %code% but its not usefull.
This statment seems to delete everything

```
DELETE
FROM location_hint 
WHERE type = 2 AND name NOT IN
(
    SELECT a.name
    FROM  airports a
    WHERE a.code IN
    (
        SELECT n_airports
        FROM location

        )
)
```

Airport table

```
CREATE TABLE airports (
    _id INTEGER,
    code TEXT,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(_id)
)
```

[image]
location table

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
    `_id`   integer,
    `country`   text,
    `city`  text,
    `n_airports`    text,
    PRIMARY KEY(_id)
)
```

[image]
location hint table

```
CREATE TABLE "location_hint" (
    `_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `type`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `country`   TEXT,
    `city`  TEXT
)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you concidered remodelling your datamodel? Having related records as comma separated values in a text fields kind of defeats the purpose of having a relational database.

Comment: @Morten unfortunatly its legacy part of the project and too much is tied up to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, scribbled quickly on notepad - but please test it

```
DELETE
FROM location_hint 
WHERE type = 2 AND name IN
(
     SELECT a.name
    FROM  airports
    MINUS
    SELECT a.name
    FROM  airports a
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM location
        WHERE INSTR(','||n_airports||',' , ','||a.code||',') > 0
        )
)
```

Comment: also, why you concatenete ','||n_airports||',' ? It is already in form KLAX, JNY, PTT etc

Comment: Freeze could be because of the outer most query. Using `NOT IN` is not a very tuned way of deleting data . Test the    
 `SELECT a.name
    FROM  airports a
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM location
        WHERE INSTR(','||n_airports||',' , ','||a.code||',') > 0
        )`
part first.

Comment: @Yarh Let me know if you are getting the expected data from the inner query or not. Also, make sure that you are accounting for the case-sensitivity and blank-spaces, IF ANY, in your comma separated string.

Comment: `','||n_airports||','` is required to make sure that **LAX** does not match **KLAX** or **ABCLAXYZ** etc.

Comment: @Yarh , I have modified the code to make it more efficient.